# Swift computed properties in Swift with instance variable?

Tags: inheritance, swift, properties, overriding, ivar

I'm trying to create a computed property in Swift and I need an instance variable to save the state of the property.

This happens specially when I'm trying to override a property in my superclass:

```
class Jedi {
    var lightSaberColor = "Blue"
}


class Sith: Jedi {
    var _color = "Red"
    override var lightSaberColor : String{
        get{
            return _color
        }
        set{
            _color = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

I'm overriding the stored property lightSaberColor in Jedi with a computed property because that's the only way the compiler will let me. It also forces me to create a getter and setter (which makes sense). And that's when I run into trouble.

So far, the only way I've found is to define this extra and ugly var `_color`. Is thee a more elegant solution?

I tried defining `_color` inside the property block, but it won't compile.

There's gotta be a better way!

Comment: Why do you need to override the property? There must be a reason behind that, and I think that can help in order to provide you a proper answer

Comment: It's just an example. The real question is how to handle iVars in computed properties

Comment: Why you open 2 questions to the same issue? Close one.

Comment: It's not the same issue. Please read the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have it is the only way it can work right now - the only change I would make is to declare `_color` as `private`.

Depending on your needs, it may be enough to have a stored property with `willGet` and/or `didSet` handlers.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set it in initializer?

```
class Jedi {
    var lightSaberColor = "Blue"
}

class Sith: Jedi {
    override init () {
        super.init()
        self.lightSaberColor = "Red"
    }
}
```